# django rest framework calculate/modify result before sending to browser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

view:

```
class ChartAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ChartSerializer
    queryset = Chart.objects.prefetch_related('attendees__person').all()

    def get_object(self):
        user = self.request.user
        last_updated = user.profile.data_last_updated
        user_events = self.queryset.filter(user=user).order_by('-created')

        data = {
            'total': user_events.count(),
            'last_updated': last_updated,
            "chart_data": user_events
        }
        return type('DashboardData', (), data)()
```

Serializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('duration', 'attendees', 'created')

class DashboardSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    total = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    last_updated = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    chart_data = EventSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
```

Result:

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "last_updated": "2020-09-22 04:49:25",
    "chart_data": [
        {
            "title": "Daily Stand-up",
            "organizer": "mailbox@phanig.com",
            "duration": "0:30",
            "attendees": "soubhagyakumar666@gmail.com, mailbox@phanig.com",
            "created": "2020-08-25 06:11:54",
            "updated": "2020-09-17 04:50:25"
        },
        {
            "title": "Daily Stand-up",
            "organizer": "mailbox@phanig.com",
            "duration": "0:30",
            "attendees": "soubhagyakumar666@gmail.com, mailbox@phanig.com",
            "created": "2020-08-25 06:11:54",
            "updated": "2020-09-17 04:50:25"
        },
        {
            "title": "Daily Stand-up",
            "organizer": "mailbox@phanig.com",
            "duration": "0:30",
            "attendees": "soubhagyakumar666@gmail.com, mailbox@phanig.com",
            "created": "2020-08-25 06:11:54",
            "updated": "2020-09-17 04:50:25"
        }
]
```

Here is my code and results i am getting .
But, before sending result to browser i wants to do some modification

Is there any way we can achive that.

Basically i wants to modify user_events data by passing it to a utils function.

Please have a look.

Expected result:

```
[{'created': '2020-08-24', 'duration': 510}, {'created': '2020-08-25', 'duration': 1260}]
```

I have already the function which is converting to it but, as the user_events is a query set i amgetting
error while getting the key.

Comment: please also include the code for EventSerializer as you need to change that one

Comment: Added that please check

Answer (score 1):

If it's fine to you to change the EventSerializer for all responses, I suggest you use a SerializerMethodField (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield ):

`obj` is an instance of each Event, and `get_duration` will be invoked instead of the default duration to change the format as you wanted for the field `duration` when serializing.

```
class EventSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    duration  = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_duration(self, obj):
        return your_custom_util(obj.duration)
```

Comment: what it will do ?

Comment: updated the answer. do I understand correctly that you want to change the `duration` ?

Comment: No not the duration. I wants to change user_events which you can see in views one key is there.

Comment: why is ChartSerializer (view) different from DashboardSerializer? what parameter does your util function expect?

Comment: It is converting duration to minute format .Both data i need